# Is it possible to use gganimate to plot a time series in real time i.e in milliseconds, as denoted by one axis?

Tags: r, gganimate

I would like to use gganimate (or something similar) to plot a time series in real-time, using the values on the x-axis, which are the time the event should occur after the origin in milliseconds. Is this (easily) possible?

An example of the dataset would be the following, where x is the time in millseconds from where the x/y point should be plotted from initialising the plot:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(2078, 2525, 2995, 3448, 3942, 4452, 4824, 
                        4998, 5445, 5973, 6478), 
                y = c(55, 58, 55, 54, 53, 48, 49, 56, 59, 57, 56))
```

Comment: I have not yet found the time to play with `{gganimate}` in more detail. However, you can call the animation with `animate(plot, ...)`. The latter accepts a nframes and fps parameter. Thus, if your data is in miliseconds fps = 1000 should get you there. Mind you that the rendering might not work with such values ... as said i have no practical experience. Documentation can be found here: https://gganimate.com/reference/animate.html

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a variety of ways to do this in gganimate. Here's a way using `transition_time`, which scales the frame appearance in time proportionately with the transition variable. First I add a point at time zero and at a time after the last point, so that it ranges in time beyond the first and last points. I also add `shadow_mark` to make the points stick around after their appearance.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gganimate)
fps = 20
df %>%
  add_row(x = c(0, 8000)) %>%
  mutate(frame = floor(x / fps)) -> df2
  

animate(
    ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, group = x)) +
    geom_point() +
    transition_time(time = frame) +
      shadow_mark(),
    fps = fps)
```

[image]